# Surface area of a cube

Tags: regions

When I try to compute the surface area of a simple cube it appears to give me the surface area of one of its faces, not the whole cube:

```
In[1]:= SurfaceArea[Cube[6]]
Out[1]= 36

In[2]:= SurfaceArea[Cuboid[{-3,-3,-3},{3,3,3}]]
Out[2]= 216
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. Interestingly if you do `CanonicalizePolyhedron[Cube[6]] // SurfaceArea`, it gives you back the correct number.

Comment: O.k, I have already asked a similar question here and received a stupid answer. The answer from WRI was also very disappointing. Try it with `SurfaceArea[DiscretizeRegion[Cube[6]]]` and you'll get the right answer (216). For me it's a bug!

Comment: In 13.2.0 bug is fixed, but SurfaceArea still looks buggy. Could someone check `SurfaceArea@ImplicitRegion[
  Abs[x + y] <= 1 && Abs[x + z] <= 1 && Abs[y + z] <= 1, {x, y, z}]`. I got some weird number instead of expected `12 Sqrt[2]`.

Comment: v12.2.0 doesn't have this bug either.